# IIS Reverse Proxy with same hostheader under condition on 2 internal frontend server

Tags: reverse-proxy, iis-10

a reverse proxy should be simple i thought but i encountered a problem. i try to accomplish the following:
ive 2 webfrontends (serverA, ServerB) which hosting a webapplication contoso.local.
then ive a server which is a reverse proxy on iis (with ARR & URL Rewrite)

the reverse proxy should send all incoming requests of contoso.local to serverA

if path123 is in the url it should send the request to serverB

i need to preserve the hostheader

so i configured the following on the reverse proxy:

- enabled the proxy in ARR
- set preservehostheader via `system.webServer/proxy"%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/proxy -preserveHostHeader:true /commit:apphost`
- added a new website in iss which has contoso.local as hostheader
- added 2 rules with the following config described in web.config of that website contoso.local:

  ```
       <rewrite>
       <outboundRules>
           <preConditions>
               <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                   <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
               </preCondition>
           </preConditions>
       </outboundRules>
       <rules>
           <clear />
           <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="^path123(.*)" />
               <conditions>
                   <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://serverB/{R:1}" />
           </rule>
           <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="(.*)" />
               <conditions>
                   <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://serverA/{R:1}" />
           </rule>

       </rules>
   </rewrite>
  ```

now if i test, ill get to serverA always. am i missing anything or is there any wrong in my logic?

Comment: Enable FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and you can see for yourself.

Comment: sadly there is no option for "rewrite" as tracing provider

Comment: ok, repaired the rewrite module installation and then it pops up